# Zebra won't print when I write filestream

Tags: c#, printing, filestream, zebra-printers, zpl

I am trying to print raw zpl data to a zebra printer using a byte array.  When I run the program nothing prints and the program passes through with no issue.  The only time it will actually print what I am asking for is if I step through and check my filestream values before I close it, the label will print. Can anyone help with what is causing this?

Update: Made suggested adjustments to code and this is a WINapp.

```
 public bool LabelPrinting(DataTable dt, string LblPath)
    {
        if (File.Exists(LblPath))
        {
            string strContent = "";
            string comport = cboPort.Text.Trim();
            StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(LblPath);

            strContent = myFile.ReadToEnd();
            myFile.Close();


            if (strContent.Length == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                char[] BigSpaceChars = { Convert.ToChar(0x09) };
                strContent = strContent.Replace(new string(BigSpaceChars), "   ");
                strContent = strContent.Replace("<CPN>", dt.Rows[0]["CPN"].ToString().ToUpper());
                strContent = strContent.Replace("<RACKASSET>", dt.Rows[0]["RACKASSET"].ToString().ToUpper());
                strContent = strContent.Replace("<LOC>", dt.Rows[0]["LOC"].ToString().ToUpper());

                Byte[] buffer = new byte[strContent.Length];
                buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strContent);

                SafeFileHandle printer = CreateFile(comport,FileAccess.ReadWrite,0,IntPtr.Zero,FileMode.Open,0,IntPtr.Zero);

                if (printer.IsInvalid == true)
                {
                    return false;
                }



                 using (FileStream com = new FileStream(printer, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        com.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        com.Flush();
                        com.Close();
                    }


                }

               return true;
            }
```

Comment: You should make use of the `using` statement with `com` because the stream will not be closed if the code before .Close() throws an exception.

Comment: or a try-catch, but using is indeed recommended

Comment: btw, is this a console app, class library, winapp, ... ?

Comment: @DieterB I put in a try-catch real quick and found a timeout error and that was due to me experimenting before I posted this.  "com.WriteTimeout" wasn't supposed to be there.

Comment: @EricJ I'm not sure what you mean by 'using'. I'm relatively new and from what I observe it seems the filestream is closing properly but there is no action from the printer.

Comment: you should flush the contents of the `Stream` before closing for example `com.Flush(); then call com.Close();`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Is this a console app, class library, winapp, ... ?

Comment: I have made corrections to my post.  I still encounter the same issue though.